# A member tuple (as opposed to member variable) of a class?

Tags: python

This is what I wish to do:

```
obj = object()
obj.(a,b,c) = 1,2,3
f(obj.(d,e))
```

This is what I know how to do:

```
obj = object()
obj.a, obj.b, obj.c = 1,2,3
```

Is there a syntax to do this in Python?

Follow-up questions:

- Was this proposed and rejected?
- Are there programming languages with this kind of syntactic sugar (member reference by tuple)?

("Why do you want to do this?" Because it feels intuitive to me to think about groups of member variables as a package sometimes. There are classes for which it makes sense, like a fixed-dimensional point, or a complex number.)

Comment: I don't think any amount of hacking `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` can get you this, because it's against the grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [sweeneyrod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21078108/2963903) answer, I've written a way to have somewhat similar syntax, taking a comma-delimited string and square brackets. Usage:

```
thing = myclass()
thing['x,y'] = 3,6
x,y = thing['x,y']
thing['x,y,z'] = 1,2,3
```

This gives

```
>>> x
3
>>> y
6
>>> thing.x
1
>>> thing.z
3
```

Class definition:

```
#user class
class myclass:
    def __getitem__(self,keys):
        keys = keys.split(',')
        return tuple(getattr(self, attr) for attr in keys)

    def __setitem__(self,keys,values):
        keys = keys.split(',')
        if len(keys) != len(values):
            raise ValueError('too many values to unpack (expected %d)'%len(keys))
        for attr,val in zip(keys, values):
            setattr(self, attr, val)
    def __delitem__(self,keys):
        keys = keys.split(',')
        for attr in keys:
            delattr(self, attr)
```

Issues:

- Overlaps with `__getitem__`, if you need it.
- Not exception-safe (can `__setattr__` throw an exception?)

I originally thought to use `thing.grouping('x,y')=3,6`, but I forgot that I can't assign to a function call.

---

Decorator version:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip as zip #python 2
except:
    pass #python 3 already has zip

#decorator
def attribute_tuple(cls):

    if not hasattr(attribute_tuple,'initialized'):
        attribute_tuple.initialized=True
        def get(self,keys):
            keys = keys.split(',')
            return tuple(getattr(self, attr) for attr in keys)
        attribute_tuple.get = get
        def set(self,keys,values):
            keys = keys.split(',')
            if len(keys) != len(values):
                raise ValueError('too many values to unpack (expected %d)'%len(keys))
            for attr,val in zip(keys, values):
                setattr(self, attr, val)
        attribute_tuple.set = set
        def delete(self,keys):
            keys = keys.split(',')
            for attr in keys:
                delattr(self, attr)
        attribute_tuple.delete = delete

    cls.__getitem__ = attribute_tuple.get
    cls.__setitem__ = attribute_tuple.set
    cls.__delitem__ = attribute_tuple.delete

    return cls

@attribute_tuple
class myclass:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is exact syntax for that, but to me this feels similar:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.point = (x, y)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "x":
            return self.point[0]
        elif name == "y":
            return self.point[1]
        else:
            raise AttributeError
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "x":
            self.point = (value, self.point[1])
        elif name == "y":
            self.point = (self.point[0], value)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

thing = Thing(4, 7)
thing.point = (3, 6)
thing.x = 5
```

Comment: The only problem is that it requires names for the groups, which means you can't do on-the-fly groupings. A twist on this: `thing.grouping('x','y','z') = 1,2,3`, where "grouping" returns an object with an overridden `__setattr__` and holds a reference to the original object, then sets the members one-by-one. Here's how I wrote it: http://pastebin.com/Zy2pKxz5

Comment: Not from me, but it reminds me why I haven't accepted the answer. Strictly speaking, your answer gave me the idea for the solution I was satisfied with, but it doesn't have that solution in the body. Would you like to edit it in, or should I post it as an answer and accept myself?

Comment: Maybe an interface like `thing.grouping('x,y,z')` with `grouping` having a call to `.split(',')` would be better.

Comment: @leewangzhong Oh, I meant this as a solution that felt similar in the idea of encapsulating a couple of variables, but also allowing seperate access. If you've written the code for `thing.grouping('x,y,z')` I suppose you might as well post it and accept it (it'll get a +1 from me).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible because of the [grammar of attribute references](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references).

> An attribute reference is a primary followed by a period and a name:

```
attributeref ::=  primary "." identifier
```

And an [identifier](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier) must begin with a letter, not parentheses.

> Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following
>   lexical definitions:

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

This means you will get a `SyntaxError` no matter how much hacking you do on `__getattr__` and/or `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "member tuple" syntax of precisely the kind you're describing. Here is a possible workaround, though, for setting "tuples" of attributes and passing "tuples" of attributes. It's kind of bulky, so I don't know if I would actually want to use it, though.

```
class MyClass:
    pass

def set_tuple(obj, **attrs):
    for key in attrs:
        setattr(obj, key, attrs[key])

def pass_tuple(obj, *attrnames):
    return (getattr(obj, x) for x in attrnames)

def print_things(*iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        print(x)

obj = MyClass()
set_tuple(obj, a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(obj.a, obj.b, obj.c, '\n')
print_things(*pass_tuple(obj, 'a', 'c'))
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 

1
3
```